# openapi3 integration with webflux functional way is not working

Tags: functional-programming, spring-webflux, swagger-ui, springdoc, openapi.net

I am trying to integrate openapi3 with reactive webflux functional endpoints. but i am always getting the error message "invalid version" from andother route configuration`.andOther(route(RequestPredicates.all(), errorHandler::invalidVersion))`. If i remove that validation swagger is working but the version validation is failing.below is my custom router.

```
route()
        .add((RouterFunction<ServerResponse>) routerFunctionMappings
            .stream()
            .map(routemapping -> Tuples.of(routemapping.getVersion(),
                routeForVersion(routemapping.getRouteMapping())))
            .reduce(Tuples.of("test", route()), (tupel2RouteFunction1, tupel2RouteFunction2) ->
                Tuples.of("test", tupel2RouteFunction1
                    .getT2()
                    .path(
                        tupel2RouteFunction2.getT1(),
                        () -> (RouterFunction<ServerResponse>) tupel2RouteFunction2
                            .getT2()
                            .build()
                            .andOther(
                                route(RequestPredicates.all(), handler::validate)))))
            .getT2()
            .build()
            .andOther(route(RequestPredicates.all(), errorHandler::invalidVersion)))
        .build()
        .filter(filterFunction());
```

Please help me how to resolve this to make both validation and swagger works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. this got resolved when I updated this line`.andOther(route(RequestPredicates.all(), errorHandler::invalidVersion))` to `.andOther(route(RequestPredicates .pathPredicates(PathPatternParser.defaultInstance) .apply("/swagger-doc/**").negate(), errorHandler::versionNotSupported))`